# Friendly URL in Liferay with a specific pattern

Tags: liferay-6, friendly-url

I am able to achieve friendly urls in Liferay 6.2 CE as follows: localhost:8080/pagename/mapping/dynamic-id

But I want it as below:

localhost:8080/pagename/dynamic-id

OR

localhost:8080/mapping/dynamic-id

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no official, neither simple way which you can already achieve what you want. Neither I wouldn't recommend it at all for common requests. Portal architecture defines it this way because, each request should clearly define informations such as:

- **page** destination (which one?)
- **portlet** (which one?)
- portlet **instance id** (when instanceable=true)
- some specified portlet **context information**

As you can see, removing any of these information can lead to situation where request can be understood in more than one way (which page? which portlet on page? which instance? which action?)

If there is no some serious reason, I wouldn't try to fight with this, since this can lead to some other problems in future. If there is no other way, just provide more information, so we maybe can find some workaround solution for your case.